# Laravel query won't return anything

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-4

For some reason this query is not working, but when I try it directly on Navicat (I make an error on purpose so I can get the query Laravel makes) it works perfectly. I want to retrieve the name of the Families along with the number of species it has. Something like:

Family 1 | 3

Family 2 | 8

Family 3 | 1

My code:

```
$sortBy .= "%";

    $familias = Familia::select(DB::raw('familias.nombre, COUNT(*) AS cantidad'))
                        ->leftJoin('especies as e', 'familias.id','=','e.id_familia')
                        ->where('familias.id', '=', 'e.id_familia')
                        ->where('familias.nombre', 'LIKE', '"'.$sortBy.'"')
                        ->groupBy('familias.id')
                        ->orderBy('familias.nombre','ASC')
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Where `$sortBy .= "%";` would be something like `A%`

Comment: Might have to add a `->get()` to the end of that query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add quotes to your LIKE string:

```
->where('familias.nombre', 'LIKE', $sortBy)
```

Using the quotes would end up double quoting them, which won't yield any results.

---

BTW, you can get to the query by using `DB::getQueryLog()`. No need to cause an error.